# Spark reduce with comparison

Tags: apache-spark

I have an RDD of tuples with the form `(key, count)` however some keys are equivalent, i.e.

```
(a,3)
(b,4)
(c,5)
```

should reduce down to... as `a` and `c` are equivalent (for example)

```
(a,8)
(b,4)
```

is there a way to perform this operation in Spark?

I'm thinking some sort of conditional within the `reduce()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think there is a way to do this within the reduce operation, but you can achieve it using a pre-processing step. One option is to create a `Map[K,K]` that links your keys.

```
val in = sc.parallelize(List(("a",3),("b",4),("c",5)))

val keyMap: Map[String,String] = Map[String,String]("a"->"a",   "b"->"b",   "c"->"a")

val out = in.map{case (k,v) => (keyMap.getOrElse(k,k),v)}.reduceByKey(_+_)

out.take(3).foreach(println)
```

Edit:

If the `Map` can't fit on the driver, you can also distribute the lookup:

```
val in = sc.parallelize(List(("a",3),("b",4),("c",5)))

val keyMap = sc.parallelize(List(("a","a"),("b","b"),("c"->"a")))

val out = in.join(keyMap).map{case (oldKey, (v, newKey)) => (newKey, v)}.reduceByKey(_+_)

out.take(3).foreach(println)
```

Comment: I was worried about that, is the Map distributed like an RDD would be? I have more keys than can fit on the driver.

Comment: The Map is serialized and passed from the driver to each of the executors. So yes, if you can't fit on the driver this will not work. I have updated the answer with an example for when the mapping needs to be distributed too :-)

Comment: This seems to work, just finished getting some fine details worked out for my specific case. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

`reduceByKey()` does the trick here as your data is already paired one.

```
val baseRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 3), ("b", 4), ("a", 5)))
baseRDD.reduceByKey((accum, current) => accum + current).foreach(println)
```

Comment: Reduce by key works for the summation but in this case `a` and `c` are not directly equivalent, they need to have a special equivalence defined.